# obtener todos los productos activos a partir de una tabla de referencia

Tags: mysql

tengo una tabla de referencia llamada `Prod_OrderAnal`; de donde quiero extraer los registros de los  productos que estén activos en la tabla del Maestro, manteniendo el orden ascendente de `Prod_OrderAnal_PrintOrder`:

**Tabla Prod_OrderAnal**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Maestro (MasterProducts)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Query:**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Prod_OrderAnal
WHERE
    Prod_Code =(
    SELECT
        Prod_Code
    FROM
        MasterProducts
    WHERE
        Prod_ST IN('1')
)
ORDER BY
    Prod_OrderAnal_PrintOrder ASC;
```

el mysql me retorna este mensaje:

> Subconsulta retorna mas que 1 línea

Comment: Tenes que reemplazar el `=` por el operador [`IN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in)

Comment: @Marcos no funciona tampoco

Comment: ¿Por que no funciona? ¿Da error? ¿No devuelve el resultado esperado?

Comment: error: Operando debe tener 1 columna(s)

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas debe tener datos de prueba, salida esperada y salida actual. Toda consulta (con sintaxis correcta) es válida dependiendo de lo que se busque.

Comment: @Alfabravo datos pudo agregarlos, salida no creo por que es lo que no conseguía... como agregas algo que no tienes, por eso agregue textualmente lo esperado??? la sintaxis tiene un problema de lógica que revienta en tiempo de ejecución, lo cual tambien fue agregado.

Comment: _Tengo una tabla_ (no la muestras), _quiero extraer los registros_ (no hay datos de prueba), _me sale este error_ (te lo resolvieron). Ya lo que salió después es OTRO problema, oculto porque tu consulta no llegaba hasta allá en el optimizador. Entonces, para que alguien llegue a proponer una consulta que funcione con tus datos y haga lo que te estás imaginando, hay que hacer saber eso que te imaginas como resultado.

Comment: hay estan los datos

Answer (score 5):

Es porque en la clausula WHERE, cuando haces un `valor = (subconsulta)`, lo que debe retornar la subconsulta es un solo valor, no muchas líneas.

Así que al final tu consulta debería quedar algo así:

```
WHERE
    Prod_Code = (Sub consulta que regresa una sola línea con una columna)
```

O:

```
WHERE
    Prod_Code IN (Sub consulta que retorna varias líneas de una columna)
```

Comment: error: Operando debe tener 1 columna(s)

Comment: es el mensaje que sal con tus cambios. no sale error de sintaxis; es un error de logica.

Comment: Entonces regresa una columna, es decir, tu `SELECT` solo debe de tener un campo, por ejemplo, `SELECT columna1 FROM ...`. Y no `SELECT * FROM ...`, tampoco`SELECT columna1, columna2 FROM ...`

Comment: necesito extraer todos los datos por eso puse en el post ***extraer los registros*** y no ***extraer un valor de una columna***